# Roundcube outgoing MAIL ERROR 550S

Tags: php, roundcube

I installed Roundcube on my MySQL server. Incoming mails are working but Outgoing mails keep failing. I have tried changing the port but it still keeps failing. Where is the error? See Code Below
../main.inc.php

```
// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------

// SMTP server host (for sending mails).
// To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://
// If left blank, the PHP mail() function is used
// Supported replacement variables:
// %h - user's IMAP hostname
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = '79.170.40.104';

// SMTP port (default is 25; use 587 for STARTTLS or 465 for the
// deprecated SSL over SMTP (aka SMTPS))
$rcmail_config['smtp_port'] = 465;

// SMTP username (if required) if you use %u as the username Roundcube
// will use the current username for login
$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = '%u';

// SMTP password (if required) if you use %p as the password Roundcube
// will use the current user's password for login
$rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';

// SMTP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or empty to use
// best server supported one)
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_type'] = '';

// Optional SMTP authentication identifier to be used as authorization proxy
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_cid'] = null;

// Optional SMTP authentication password to be used for smtp_auth_cid
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_pw'] = null;

// SMTP HELO host 
// Hostname to give to the remote server for SMTP 'HELO' or 'EHLO' messages 
// Leave this blank and you will get the server variable 'server_name' or 
// localhost if that isn't defined. 
$rcmail_config['smtp_helo_host'] = '';

// SMTP connection timeout, in seconds. Default: 0 (no limit)
// Note: There's a known issue where using ssl connection with
// timeout > 0 causes connection errors (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54511)
$rcmail_config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;
```

Comment: You seem to be using SSL and based on this comment `// To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://` your hostname should be ssl://79.170.40.104/

Comment: you should ask to http://superuser.com